# Hide ClearButton from Primefaces-Mobile InputText

Tags: jquery, jsf, jquery-mobile, jakarta-ee, primefaces

I'm using Primefaces 5.0 and I'm trying to build a mobile Page. Primefaces-Mobile is built on jQuery Mobile.

The following line

```
<p:inputText value="#{whatever}"  />
```

is giving me this output:

[image]

This is because they are using the [Clear button option](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0-beta.1/docs/forms/textinputs/index.html) of jQuery Mobile. As you can see my textfield is pretty small and I need the space the clear button is taking, so I want to remove it.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Primefaces-Mobile is known for not fully supporting all jQuery Mobile features.

First try this just so you can so you can check if this is supported:

```
<p:inputText value="#{whatever}" pt:data-clear-btn="false"/>
```

If it doesn't work you can cheat:

#### HTML:

```
<div class="remove-clear">
    <p:inputText value="#{whatever}"/>
</div>
```

#### CSS:

```
.remove-clear .ui-input-text a {
    display: none;
}

.remove-clear .ui-input-has-clear {
    padding-right: 0 !important;        
}
```

working example (unfortunately I can only show you how to cheat directly in jQuery Mobile) : http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/jwtgq/